# The name Invoicee1 does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My project seems to have a common problem where 'the name X does not exist in the current context. The project is an invoice page, with a print page where textbox data is pulled from the invoice page, and displayed/calculated on the print page.

Essentially, while completing my project, I was hoping to successfully pull one textbox through to the next page before adding the rest of the data to be pulled. The assignment itself does not require the data to be in a cell table, just collect and present the data in a faux-invoice appearance.

I'll be storing data via the session method. Although this ID not being recognized is causing a roadblock with the project.

After having a look via a number of answers to the same question here, I have attempted manually updating the designer page to include the ID and the result was unsuccessful; I've also deleted and rewritten the file, have checked all other older files and unused files and was unsuccessful in finding a reason. There's clearly something I'm not seeing here, I'm hoping that someone might be able to see something I cannot!

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="invoice.aspx.cs" Inherits="invoice" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Invoice</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
    <h1>Invoice</h1>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
                                <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" BackColor="#B5C7DE" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284E98" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px">
        <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
        <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
        <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" />
        <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/edit.aspx" Text="Edit Registrations" Value="Edit Registrations"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Invoice.aspx" Text="Invoice" Value="Invoice"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/index.aspx" Text="Home" Value="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/chart.aspx" Text="Chart" Value="Chart"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/stocktake.aspx" Text="Stocktake" Value="Stocktake"></asp:MenuItem>
        </Items>
        <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
        <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
        <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
    </asp:Menu>
        <div>
            <p>
            <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" CellPadding="10" HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
                Invoicee
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Invoicee1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>

            </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
                Item name:
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
                Unit price:
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
                Quantity:
        </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Item1" runat="server" Placeholder="Item"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Price1" runat="server" Placeholder="Unit Price"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Stock1" runat="server" Placeholder="Stock Quantity"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Item2" runat="server" Placeholder="Item"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Price2" runat="server" Placeholder="Unit Price"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Stock2" runat="server" Placeholder="Stock Quantity"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Item3" runat="server" Placeholder="Item"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Price3" runat="server" Placeholder="Unit Price"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Stock3" runat="server" Placeholder="Stock Quantity"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" PostBackUrl="~/print.aspx"/>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>

        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>

        </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>

            </asp:Table>
        </div>
    </form>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the codebehind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace _assessment3
{
    public partial class invoice : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["Invoicee"] = Invoicee1.Text;

            Response.Redirect("~/print.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result is that the invoicee will be added to the session.

Comment: Curious why you are doing a Response.Redirect() but you also have a PostBackUrl?

Comment: Yes, the invoice page didn't seem to redirect to print.aspx even though I had the response.redirect in the code behind.

Comment: You'll have to remove the postbackurl and figure out why the redirect is not working. The code-behind won't run with the postbackurl there.

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Redirect` requires a *URL*:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.microsoft.com/gohere/look.htm");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!

The issue (for some reason) was fixed when I deleted the .aspx file, added a new one, and created the form without using a tablecell. Either the problem was textbox IDs not functioning properly when they're inside a celltable, or there was something else I was missing.

Either way, problem solved!